# Oracle PL/SQL. Group by on clob data

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to Oracle PL/SQL. I have question on “creating views, group by based on clob”.

**TABLE1 = EMPLOYEE**

```
EMP_ID   : NUMBER
EMP_NAME : VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
AGE      : NUMBER
```

**TABLE2 = EMPLOYEE_WORK**

```
EMP_ID   : NUMBER
DEPT_NO  : NUMBER
WORK_DONE: CLOB
```

**Sample VIEW Query:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE view EMP_DETAILS 
as 
select E.EMP_ID, 
       E.EMP_NAME, 
       W.DEPT_NO, 
       W.WORKDONE 
from EMPLOYEE E, 
     EMPLOYEE_WORK W 
where E.EMP_ID=W.EMP_ID 
group by E.EMP_ID, E.EMP_NAME, W.DEPT_NO, W.WORKDONE;
```

I want to perform group by only based on DEPT_NO. Since oracle doesn’t support that. I had to give all the columns in VIEW under GROUP BY. I don’t want to explicitly convert the clob into VARCHAR and perform the group by operation, because I don’t know what the size of the clob will be and there is no reason for it to be present in the GROUP BY list.

Is there any way to perform this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would the results be?

Comment: When you say "GROUP BY" do you actually mean "DISTINCT"?

Comment: Plz elaborate what end result do you want. there are various ways we can achieve or as an alternative to GROUP BY

Comment: What results were you trying to obtain from your view? I'm sure that Oracle will allow `GROUP BY DEPT_NO` if you're trying to use `GROUP BY` correctly. Are you perhaps looking for a way to obtain all the employees in a particular department? In that case you want to say `WHERE DEPT_NO=xyz` rather than `GROUP BY DEPT_NO`.

Answer (score -1):

To echo what sagi and Avraji have asked, "What do you want to do?" And, extending what Boneist says, your view does essentially a distinct.

Generally, with a group by, you're doing an aggregate thing, such as a count. Web search "Oracle group by."

Even tho you don't necessarily know the length of the CLOB, you are probably only going to order by a finite number of characters. Web search DBMS_LOB for functions such as dbms_lob.substr eg dbms_lob.substr( w.WORK_DONE, 100, 1 ) that may get you what you desire.

Comment: This is not an answer - it's a series of guesses, and should be a comment. OP needs to provide clarification for the question. I suggest you wait until the question is in a state where it *can* be answered.

Comment: I cannot comment until I get enough points. 

Altho your point may be valid, it doesn't seem the poster knows what s/he wants to do and may need help getting to the next step. I was hoping to assist that.